# Formula to find out a $b_3, b_4, b_5$ coefficient independent variable for multiple linear regression

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I have been given this formula to find the coefficients $b_1$ and $b_2$ as in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bqnq.png) :

$b_1 = \left(\dfrac{r_{y,x_1}-r_{y,x_2}r_{x_1,x_2}}{1-(r_{x_1,x_2})^2} \right) \left( \dfrac{SD_y}{SD_{x_1}}\right)$

$b_2 = \left(\dfrac{r_{y,x_2}-r_{y,x_1}r_{x_1,x_2}}{1-(r_{x_1,x_2})^2} \right) \left( \dfrac{SD_y}{SD_{x_2}}\right)$

My question is what would the formula for coefficient $b_3, b4$ and $b_5$ look like. I have been unable to find this whilst searching the web.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question?

Comment: What is your model?